# How to obtain a more specific error message when using node.js spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Right now I have the following code to spawn a python script in node.js:

```
  logger.info('Spawning python process');
    let proc1 = spawn('python3',
      ['experimental/paraphrase/paraphrase_detect.py',
        results[0].answer, request.query.response]);

    proc1.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      logger.info('Python script returned data');
      let retVal;
      if (data) {
        logger.info(data.toString());
        retVal = JSON.parse(data.toString());
      }

      return response.json({data: retVal});
    });

    proc1.on('close', (code, test) => {
      if (code === 1) {
        const msg = 'Python exited with exit code 1 meaning there was a ' +
            'problem executing the script.';
        logger.error(msg);
        logger.error(test);
      }
    });

    proc1.on('error', (data) => {
      logger.error('Error with calling python script');
      if (data) {
        logger.error(data.toString());
      }
    });
```

The issue I'm dealing with is that specific error messages aren't being returned to node, such as permissions issues, a misspelling of the script name or a missing python package. The best I've been able to do so far is catch an exit code of 1 which just indicates generically that there was a problem running the script.

Comment: The code is already doing that. What I am asking for is a more specific error message.

Comment: Try proc1.stderr.on("data")

Comment: That did it - thanks @Darkrum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try proc1.stderr.on("data")

More details.
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process